# Hive select: There is no output for this job

Tags: hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I ran a select statement as a test, and the job output was available in the job history with a 'download file'.

I then ran another select statement that would produce many more rows, and the job output displays: There is no output for this job...

Is the result of the query in the file system somewhere?

Note this is via the HDInsight query console (hadoop 3.3.0.844, windows operating system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more info about the job in your storage container under mapred/done!